# What is the best way to convert image to ASCIIHexDecode format for use in a PDF file

Tags: image, pdf, pdf-generation

Image(PNG/JPG/ICON) to ASCIIHexDecode conversion

I need to convert an image to ASCIIHexDecode format so that I can use it into my pdf file.

I tried to convert into ASCII and then Hex with some online tools as well, but image getting corrupted in the pdf file. Suggest me if there any better approach or library so that I can convert it properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would like to have "text safe" image. So I thought using ASCIIHEX conversion of the image. What do you mean by " need a graphics application" ? Do I need use any specific tool to convert from image to ASCIIHEX format?

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken about what is involved here. ASCIIHexDecode (or FlateDecode etc.) are filters which are applied to the raw image data. A PNG or JPEG or ICON file is not raw image data.

A JPG file doesn't need converting to be included in a PDF. You just include it directly and mark it with filter DCTDecode.

For a PNG file, you can extract the IDAT chunks from the file and then concatenate them, and mark it with filter FlateDecode. But this requires reading the PNG file format.

An easier way might be to convert your non-JPEG images (PNG, ICO) might be to convert them first with `convert` to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm format, and then write a simple program which reads that and converts it to binary data to put in the PDF file. You can use any of the non-lossy filter types for this data, or indeed none at all.

Comment: Thanks for the information. There is a problem with DCT decode filter as it has nulls and getting replaced with space when copied. I would like to use ASCIIHex filter which is text safe. So I need a way to convert image to ASCIIHex format.

Comment: @Sandhya Out of curiosity - what kinds of copying are you thinking about? Being worried about nulls getting replaced by spaces reminds me of the situation at the end of the last century with Windows 98 any earlier versions with their MS DOS underneath. It's that really still a worry in some context nowadays?

Comment: @mkl Hi, it is because I tried to extract an image from a pdf file. Where I copied the image data to another pdf file and the image is with filter DCTDecode. When copied it replaced all the NUL values into spaces. That is the reason I am trying to convert image into another text safe filter (ASCIIHexDecode).

Comment: *"When copied it replaced all the NUL values into spaces"* - if I were you, I'd ask about ways to improve your copying method here. You're currently not trying to solve your issue but to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Plain text image formats are usually not compressed, since compression by definition is never plain text.

so for example a 32 pixel square icon will become 3 KB when we do the maths 32 x 32 x 3 bytes = 3072 bytes

The bigger problem is when cut and pasted here as text, it will be corrupted, by bit rot.

```
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ��ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ�ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ���m9r;���ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ��
Úr ÿ‹'< ÿÿÿ�ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ�ÿÿÿ1ô…%Ûu!
��ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ��‹I¼e
ÿÿÿj7ÿ‘)©Yÿÿÿ���ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ—Oÿ’)Ôp 0ÿÿÿ¥Vÿ“)n9ÿÿÿ�ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿq;ÿŠ'ð€$K'�Øs úˆ&5ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ�ÿÿÿI&2ÿÿÿÿÿÿN(ò$ÿŒ'c4%ô…%æz"���ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ���ð~#ÿ‹'£V:  ÿÿÿ Öq ÿ•*C|@ŸT���ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ�Q*ºbÿŒ'ÿ‹'·`?!       ¥Wÿ•*U-
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ7ªYÿŠ'ÿ’)¾d[/
f6��ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ    Jf52�ÿÿÿ†Gõ%ÿ…&ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ2ÿ‹'ÿ‘)ÿŒ'ï~#Áf€CF%
N)[0ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿHHHIHHÿÿÿ)U-
‹IÀeî|#ÿ(ÿ‘)ÿŒ(=^\[)))ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ³²²´³³ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ/^1›R�*.1äâáfffÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ¤££©¦¥ÿÿÿn:Ýx"ÒnÕpÓoÍlÆhÁeÇi
�&*-ÑÏÏ]]]ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ§¦¦¬©¨yAî‚'àw#äy$äy$åz%çz%è{%í("(-/ÕÓÒ___ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ§¦¦¦¥¥ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ%%%ÔÓÓ___ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ¢¡¡³²²[ZZZZ[YZ[ZZ[ZZ[ZZ[ZZ[ZZ[ZZ[[[\[[[rqqÌËË___ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ©¨¨ÎÍÍÒÑÑÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÓÔÓÒÔÓÒÍÌÌÔÓÓfffÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ...777222222222222222222222222222222222222:99ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

Bit rotten image = [image]

So one way round that is convert into a textual form which is expanded up to twice so the 3 KB bytes as HEXidecimal format will be 6 KB

/ASCIIHEX

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF030100020100FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000201FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0100000201000502016D3910723B11000000030201FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0101000101000D0702DA7220FF8B273C1F09FFFFFF030200FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF030100FFFFFF311A07F48525DB7521130A03010100010100FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0201000201008B4915BC651C150A03FFFFFF6A370FFF9129A95919FFFFFF030200010000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF050201060301974F16FF9229D47020301907FFFFFFA55618FF93296E3910FFFFFF040200FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF713B11FF8A27F080244B270B010100D87320FA8826351B08FFFFFF0301FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF010100FFFFFF49260B321A07FFFFFFFFFFFF4E280BF28124FF8C2763340F251305F48525E67A22160B03010000010100FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF010100010000100802F07E23FF8B27A356183A1F09FFFFFF201105D67120FF952A7F43137C40129F54180F0802010100010000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0101000B0602512A0CBA621BFF8C27FF8B27B7601B3F2109110902A55719FF952A552D0DFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF371D08AA5919FF8A27FF9229BE641C5B2F0D66360F060301030200010100FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF030303040303FFFFFF1009028D4A1566350F321A07020100FFFFFF1C0F04864714F58125FF85260F0803030303030302FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF321A07FF8B27FF9129FF8C27EF7E23C1661D80431346250A4E290C5B300EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF484848494848FFFFFF070401291506552D0D8B4914C0651CEE7C23FF8D28FF9129FF8C283D1E050F11135E5C5B292929FFFFFF010101FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB3B2B2B4B3B3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0B05022F19075E310E9B52191D0B002A2E31E4E2E1666666FFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA4A3A3A9A6A5FFFFFF6E3A10DD7822D26E1FD5701FD36F1FCD6C1EC6681DC1651CC7691F1A0A00262A2DD1CFCF5D5D5DFFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7A6A6ACA9A8030303794114EE8227E07723E47924E47924E57A25E77A25E87B25ED7F28220F03282D2FD5D3D25F5F5FFFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA7A6A6A6A5A5FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF252525D4D3D35F5F5FFFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFA2A1A1B3B2B25B5A5A5A5A5B595A5B5A5A5B5A5A5B5A5A5B5A5A5B5A5A5B5A5A5B5B5B5C5B5B5B727171CCCBCB5F5F5FFFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF010101A9A8A8CECDCDD2D1D1D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D3D4D3D2D4D3D2CDCCCCD4D3D3666666FFFFFF030303FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2E2E2E3737373232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323A39391C1C1CFFFFFF010101FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202030303010101FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

and with luck in a PDF that will look like an SO logo, which we can use at any scale however all those FFFFFF in groups of *6* ONLY would be set to FFFFFF for a white background  [image]
[image]

So as to convert that stream into an image we need to say width 32 height 32 8 bits per color and length 3072 (not real 6144)

Now this is very inefficient method for such a simple HTML/PDF logo which will never scale well, and could be easier described as, a grey rectangle with smaller white rectangle and 5 rotating orange rectangles, thus 7 short lines of PDF `re` code.

For every "Image" you need to decide which may be the most efficient description.
Monochrome pixels, vector image or RGB ? and when we decide on RGB, do we need CMYK or RGBA or simplest lossy jpg as most suitable for photo style.

Here we can define the SOlogo as 6 coloured blocks and by working real-time in Notepad and a previewer every CTRL+S will show the effect in the preview so here tweaking the block highlighted in red, and we can see I am editing one X-object but it has been referenced twice (2 for the price of 1) see comment below.

[image]

I realised that in making it convenient to draw as an image (1 0 0 -1) the matrix origin is "image" top left thus placements in the PDF become slightly more of an issue as Y needs to be negative, in the page.

```
%PDF-1.5
%ÂÂÂÂ
1 0 obj <</Pages 2 0 R/Type/Catalog>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]/Type/Pages>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Rotate 0/MediaBox[0 0 316 316]/Contents 5 0 R/Group<</CS/DeviceRGB/I true/S/Transparency/Type/Group>>/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</a0<</ca .85/CA .85>>>>/XObject<</x1 4 0 R>>>>/Type/Page>> endobj
4 0 obj <</BBox[0 0 158 158]/Group<</CS/DeviceRGB/I true/S/Transparency/Type/Group>>/Length 0504/Resources<</ExtGState<</a0<</ca .85/CA .85>>>>>>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>
stream
q /a0 gs
.7333 .7333 .7333 rg 33.5 91.5 m 42.5 91.5 l 42.5 116.5 l 102.5 116.5 l 102.5 91.5 l 111.5 91.5 l 111.5 125.5 l 33.5 125.5 l 33.5 91.5 l f*
.9529 .5020 .1373 rg
50.5 99.5 m 94.5 99.5 l 94.5 108.5 l 50.5 108.5 l 50.5 99.5 l f*
53.0 79.5 m 96.0 89.0 l 94.5 98.0 l 51.5 89.5 l 53.0 79.5 l f*
100.5 77.5 m 67.5 49.0 l 74.0 41.5 l 106.5 71.0 l 100.5 77.5 l f*
87.5 28.5 m 115.0 63.0 l 108.0 68.5 l 80.5 34.0 l 87.5 28.5 l f*
1 0 0 rg
100.0 79.0 m
96.0 86.5 l
56.5 68.0 l
61.0 59.5 l
100.0 79.0 l
f*
Q
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj <</Length 60>>
stream
q /a0 gs 1 0 0 -1 0 158 cm /x1 Do 1 0 0 1 0 -158 cm /x1 Do Q
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000111 00000 n 
0000000326 00000 n 
0000001030 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R/ID[<FAF44F9F57842C6CC0CDDCD392B355A9><BF3D43D6313F32432BD1A1208C49D39B>]>>
startxref
1139
%%EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. You are right. I just tried the image text you shared and it didn't scaled the image well in the pdf file. So, for example lets take any sample logo under this random site" https://depositphotos.com/vector-images/sample-logo.html " .  I need to add a company logo to my invoice. In this case which way you suggest?

Comment: This is nice. But it is not possible to draw the images like this always right. If we consider a rose flower then we can't draw it like this right. If I really has an image and need to import into pdf don't we have another way to do it?